# Asp.Net MVC JsonResult throwing 'Root element is missing' error in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

I have an MVC 5 web application with the following JsonResult

```
public JsonResult GetCartSummary()
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(HttpContext);
        var results = new ShoppingCartSummaryViewModel
        {
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
            CartCount = cart.GetCount()
        };
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

If i test it locally on IIS Express or on Windows Azure i get a valid response like below:

```
{"CartTotal":0,"CartCount":0}
```

But when i upload it to our production server (IIS 8 running on Server 2012 R2) its throws the following exception:

```
Message: Root element is missing.
StackTrace:    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor.Decompress(Byte[] bytes)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel(String& migrationId, String& productVersion, String contextKey)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModel(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
at PlayingPlayers.Models.ShoppingCart.GetTotal()
at PlayingPlayers.Controllers.ShoppingCartController.GetCartSummary()
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Source: System.Xml
TargetSite: Void Throw(System.Exception)
```

Am i missing a library that needs to be uploaded or is there a setting in IIS8 that i am missing? Thanks

Comment: The stacktrace says it is occurring in `cart.GetTotal()`. Has nothing to do with JSON I think. Looks more like some problem with model data in the migrations table.

Answer (score 0):

By Default Server 2012 R2 uses .net version 4.5.1.

And you might be using latest version of Entity Framework which is not compatible with with the server. I hope installing latest .Net Framework on Server will resolve your problem. 
try this one https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344